# Perl, matching files of a directory, using an array with part of the these file names

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, grep

So, I have this directory with files named like this:

```
HG00119.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.low_coverage.20101123.bam.bai
HG00119.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.exome.20120522.bam_herc2_data.bam
HG00117.mapped.illumina.mosaik.GBR.exome.20110411.bam_herc2_phase1.bam
HG00117.mapped.illumina.mosaik.GBR.exome.20110411.bam.bai
NA20828.mapped.illumina.mosaik.TSI.exome.20110411.bam_herc2_phase1.bam
NA20828.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.TSI.low_coverage.20130415.bam_herc2_data.bam
```

And I have a input.txt file that contains in each line.

```
NA20828  
HG00119
```

As you can see, the input.txt file has the beginning of the name of the files inside the directory.

What I want to do is to filter the files in the directory that have the name (in this case just the beginning), inside the input.txt.
I don't know if I was clear, but here is the code I've done so far.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines;                              
my @files = glob("*.mapped*");

open (my $input,'<','input.txt') or die $!;         
while (my $line = <$input>) {
    push (@lines, $line);               
}
close $input;
```

I used the glob to filter only the files with mapped in the name, since I have other files there that I don't want to look for.

I tried some foreach loops, tried grep and regex also, and I'm pretty sure that I was going in the right way, and I think my mistake might be about scope.

I would appreciate any help guys! thanks!

Comment: Just for note. I used the command.
    print map {"$_\n"} @lines; 
To see if my input.txt was inside the array @list and it worked....at least this :)

Comment: Unless you're doing more within the `while` loop than just `push`ing the individual lines into an array you might as well just: `@lines = <$input>;`

Comment: Something like this you mean?
    `open (FILE, 'input.txt');
    chomp (my @input = (<FILE>));
    close(FILE);`

But I got what you wanted to say!

Comment: I'd stick with the lexical file handles instead of switching to the global bare word versions, but otherwise, you've got the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, first off - your while loop is redundant. If you read from a filehandle in a list context, it reads the whole thing.

```
my @lines = <$input>;
```

will do the same as your while loop.

Now, for your patterns - you're matching one list against another list, but partial matches.

```
chomp ( @lines );
foreach my $file ( @files ) {
    foreach my $line ( @lines ) {
        if ( $file =~ m/$line/ ) { print "$file matches $line"; }
    }
}
```

(And yes, something like grep or map can do this, but I always find those two make my head hurt - they're neater, but they're implicitly looping so you don't really gain much algorithmic efficiency).

Comment: It's ironic that you recommend hiding the loop with `my @lines = <$input>` and then reject doing the same thing with `grep`!

Comment: It's not so much loop hiding, as I find both grep and map prone to making hard to understand code. A matter of opinion, I will grant, but will tend to avoid them when offering solutions. Your code below is a perfect example - entirely correct, efficient and concise, but something I had to look at twice as a less experienced programmer to understand what it was doing.

Comment: Yes, I agree they are prone to misuse. I like to think that when they appear in my code they make it clearer than the equivalent `for`, but of course that's always a matter of perception, like some people can't handle `unless`. But surely you would choose a simple `@matches = grep /pattern/, @list` over the equivalent `for` and `push`?

Comment: Probably, yes. Matter of taste and style so nothing I'm firmly adverse to - and something I tend to use more in my code than I would in snippets. To each their own really :)

Comment: Nice @Sobrique! As a new guy in programming I indeed think the code of @Sobrique easier to understand. But the @Borodin is also a really good one, especially the thing about `quotemeta` .
Thank you both! I'll come with the answer @Sobrique, if it worked of not for me!!

Comment: @guidebortoli: If you're going with this answer then you will need to `chomp @lines` before the `for` loop for it to work properly. Also, my point about regex metacharacters applies here as well.

Comment: Edited to include - well spotted.

Comment: @Sobrique. Worked! I'll give you the positive answer because yours was easier for me to understand! Thank you very much, I really appreciated!!!

Comment: About the `chomp @lines` I could figured out by myself! At least this, hahaha! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can build a regular expression from the contents of `input.txt` like this

```
my @lines = do {    
    open my $fh, '<', 'input.txt' or die $!;         
    <$fh>;
};
chomp @lines;
my $re = join '|', @lines;
```

and then find the required files using

```
my @files = grep /^(?:$re)/, glob '*.mapped*';
```

Note that, if the list in `input.txt` contains any regex metacharacters, such as `.`, `*`, `+` etc. you will need to escape them, probably using `quotemeta` like this

```
my $re = join '|', map quotemeta, @lines;
```

and it may be best to do this anyway unless you are *certain* that there will *never ever* be such characters in the file.

Comment: Thank you very much @Borodin. I'll have a look now and see if it'll work for me (which probably will)...

Comment: Alright @Borodin!!! Your code worked for me. I'll stick with the answer of @Sobrique, because for me it was easier to understand. But You code also worked!!! thank you very much!!!!